# group_by_ deprecated - I encounter issues using group_by instead

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I am trying to create a graphic on a shiny app that looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of what the graph looks like]

However, when launching my app I get the warning that `group_by_` is deprecated and that I should use `group_by` instead. This warning is making my app freeze so this is quite a serious issue.

Whenever I use `group_by`instead, the graph starts looking like this:

[image: Screenshot of what it looks like when I swtich to group_by]

Here is my code:

```
  # Density plot
  output$densityplot <- renderPlotly({
  datacount = data.frame()
    
  year_selected <- input$my_selected4
  for (i in year_selected) {
    datacount_temp <- get(i) %>% 
        group_by_(input$variable_selected) %>%
        count(input$variable_selected) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        mutate(MY = i)
      datacount <- rbind(datacount,datacount_temp)
  }

    datacount <- datacount %>% group_by(MY) %>% mutate(density = n/sum(n))
    colnames(datacount)[1] <- "category"
```

Comment: slightly off topic but might enhance the speed quite a bit: using rbind in a for loop is terribly inefficient and slow. you can change the whole for loop into a call to `lapply()`.

Comment: Simply passing a character string will not work. Try with using the `.data` pronoun, i.e. do `group_by(.data[[input$variable_selected]])` but even easier would be to do `get(i) %>% count(.data[[input$variable_selected]]) %>% mutate(..`, i.e. the group_by + ungroup is not necessary when using count.

Comment: Both solutions worked perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: You can find more information here about why `.data[[]]` is used if you want: [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Comment: Since I’m mostly a base R thinker, this has me wondering when I missed the memo about the replacement of “.” by “.data”.